# Parse a nested JSON with Python and return human-readable info

Tags: python, json

I need to parse a nested JSON file with python and return the human-readable information back to the user.

I have tried applying a map() function alomg with dictionary that provides interpretation, but it seems to be not working with nested JSONs (or I am doing it wrong). The problem is also that the keys at level 2 may repeat as shown below, both 'consumable' and 'coin' have '1' and '2' inside them:

My JSONs look like this:

```py
{
"consumable": {
"1": 5,
"2": 10
},
"coin": {
"1": 2000,
"2": 5000
},
"gold": 10000
}
```

What I expect from my script is that when I copy the JSON, I will receive a human-readable data, so 'consumable 1: 5' becomes 'mana potion: 5 pcs', ''consumable 2: 10' becomes 'HP potion: 10 pcs', and 'coin 1: 2000' becomes 'dollar: 2000', 'coin 2: 5000' becomes 'euro: 5000' and so on.
There are also things without nesting there so they should parse just like regular JSONs.

I'm not even a programmer, and have no idea how this might be done.

Comment: you might want to look at the built in `json` library. it has functions that can read json and convert to a python dictionary. you can print the `json` with nice indenting using the built in `pprint` (pretty print) library

Comment: The first step would be that you would need to provide a systematic mapping from the keys in the data example you give to the "readable" alternatives you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very pretty but does what you're expecting:

```
import json
json_string = '{ "consumable": { "1": 5, "2": 10 }, "coin": { "1": 2000, "2": 5000 }, "gold": 10000}'

content = json.loads(json_string)

for elem in content:
    if elem == 'consumable':
        for index in content[elem]:
            if index == '1':
                print(f'mana potion: {content[elem][index]} pcs')
            elif index == '2':
                print(f'HP potion: {content[elem][index]} pcs')
    elif elem == 'coin':
        for index in content[elem]:
            if index == '1':
                print(f'dollar: {content[elem][index]}')
            elif index == '2':
                print(f'euro: {content[elem][index]}')
```

This prints:

> mana potion: 5 pcs
>   HP potion: 10 pcs
>   dollar: 2000
>   euro 5000

A nicer way would be to create a mapping dictionary between json and human readable strings.

Comment: Sir, you, sir, just saved my life! Thank you so much!